# WPF Draw primitives in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, itemtemplate

I am making program for representation of network graph. I have here many attributes for connection between two nodes. Actually I am trying make a combobox with types of dashes like in [MS Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrF5A.png). My code of ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Dashes}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas >
                <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="100" Y2="100" StrokeDashArray="{Binding Dash}"/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Code behind:

```
private DoubleCollection _dash;
private List<DoubleCollection> _listOfDashes;

public DoubleCollection Dash
{
    get { return _dash; }
    set
    {
        _dash = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Dash");
    }
}

public List<DoubleCollection> Dashes
{
    get { return _listOfDashes; }
    set
    {
        _listOfDashes = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Dashes");
    }
}
```

After launch the program the ComboBox isn't empty (there is two selectable object) but items are empty. Where I am making a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the `ItemsSource` property to your ViewModel `Dashes` property. It means that every `ItemTemplate` can be bound on each element of the `Dashes` collection (i.e. a `DoubleCollection`).

Try to change your XAML in this way:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Dashes}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="100" Y2="0" StrokeDashArray="{Binding}" Stroke="Black" Margin="6" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

It means that each `Line` has its `StrokeDashArray` binded to each `DoubleCollection` that belongs to `Dashes` collection. So in this way:

```
vm = new ViewModel();
vm.Dashes = new List<DoubleCollection>();
vm.Dashes.Add(new DoubleCollection());
vm.Dashes[0].Add(2);
vm.Dashes[0].Add(3);

vm.Dashes.Add(new DoubleCollection());
vm.Dashes[1].Add(1);
vm.Dashes[1].Add(4);
```

you will see two different lines in your `ComboBox`. I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly.